# How to vectorize this for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

How to vectorize the below code?

Here `x_cords` and `y_cords` are both 7894 * 1 vectors, and `buffImg` is a dummy zeroes image and I am trying to map cords and get a segment image.

```
for i = 1:length(x_cords)
   buffImg(y_cords(i),x_cords(i)) = 1;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to transform your subscripted indexes stored in `x_cords` and `y_cords` into linear indexes using the `sub2ind`-function and then you can directly assign the ones like this:

```
buffImg=zeros(100,100);
x=randperm(100);
y=randperm(100);
buffImg(sub2ind(size(buffImg),x,y))=1;
```

Just to show you that, the output is the same, here's how you can test it:

```
x=randperm(100);
y=randperm(100);
buffImg=zeros(100,100);
buffImg2=zeros(100,100);
for i = 1:length(x)
   buffImg(x(i),y(i)) = 1;
end
buffImg2(sub2ind(size(buffImg),x,y))=1;
all(all(buffImg==buffImg2))
```

Comment: The output is not as expected, the size of buffImg is 3328 *  2560 if it is useful, so a total of 8519680 pixels among which 7894 cords have to be made 1's

Comment: I tried your code and my code and it had the exact same output. Are you sure, you didn't do anything wrong? I added some code to show you the equivalence of your output and mine.

Comment: oops sorry I got it, u used x_cords, y_cords instead of y_cords, x_cords .

Comment: Thanks, It is really helpful

Comment: Yep, I did it that way round, because that's the more common order. You're welcome.